# is it possible to create one local .aar file that contains locally all of the dependencies inside the gradle file?

Tags: android, aar

I want to create one `.aar` file that will contain *locally* all of the dependencies inside the `build.gradle (app)` file. I have tried to turn on the `transitive` property to be `true` but it didn't download the dependencies I needed.

```
compile (project(':project')) {
    transitive = true
}
```

grade files:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'


android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 35
        versionName "2.1.11"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

        manifestPlaceholders = [onesignal_app_id: "********",
                                // Project number pulled from dashboard, local value is ignored.
                                onesignal_google_project_number: "REMOTE"]

        renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
        renderscriptTargetApi 26 //must match target sdk and build tools, 23+
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    signingConfigs {

        release {
            storeFile file('../*****.jks')
            storePassword '**********'
            keyAlias '*****'
            keyPassword '**********'
        }
        debug {
            storeFile file('../*******.jks')
            storePassword '**********'
            keyAlias '*********'
            keyPassword '**********'
        }
    }
    dexOptions {
        jumboMode true
    }
}

apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')


    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha2'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.2'

    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:10.2.4'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:10.2.4'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:10.2.4'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:10.2.4'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.2.4'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.2.4'

    compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.6'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.15.0'
    compile 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.1.17'


    compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.10.2'

    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'

    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'

    compile 'com.facebook.rebound:rebound:0.3.4'

    compile 'me.grantland:autofittextview:0.2.+'

    compile 'com.koushikdutta.ion:ion:2.2.1'

    compile 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.2.10'

}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

second one:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'


        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.21.7'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}


allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
        google()
    }
}

task copyLibs(type: Copy) {
    from { configurations.compile }
    into 'libs'
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: I'm confused, you have a library module and when you compile it the dependencies are not being included in the `aar`?

Comment: yes, they do not.

Comment: how can you tell that they're not being included? are you decompiling the `aar`?

Comment: i also decompiled and they were not in the `libs` folder and also when i tried to run my module in another app it throws an exception that for example: `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError failed resolution of lcom/android/volley/toolbox/volley`

Comment: please post your `build.gradle` files, by default dependencies are included, otherwise the library would be unusable

Comment: i updated my post with the gradle files from the library module